# I have the following OCaml code, what would be the output for static scoping and dynamic scoping?

Tags: dynamic-programming, static-analysis, ocaml

```
let n = 1 in
let plus_and_print x = print (x + n) in
let incrementBy2_and_print a = 
  let n = n + 2 in
  plus_and_print n in
(* Notice: arg a of incrementBy2_and_print is not used *)
let n = 100 in
(plus_and_print 5;
 let n = 40 in (incrementBy2_and_print 0; print n))
```

I would like to know what would be the output for static scoping and dynamic scoping. I read OCaml is static and therefore there shouldn't be a dynamic output but, if there isnt, what would be the output given a language supports dynamic scoping?

Thank you!

I ran the code on the editor and it gave me the outputs 6, 4, 40 but after researching online I believe that it might be incorrect.